# like button internet explorer white box appearing

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, iframe, facebook-like

I have some code to display a like button and this shows but with a random white box that i dont really want. Works in all other browsers

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><body>


<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<SITE URL>"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"><iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: white box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the `iframe` and instead opened another one. Try changing the second `<iframe>` to `</iframe>`.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue.

Closing the iframe tag did not provide a solution to my problem.

Use the following:

```
<iframe style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';" src="../examples/inlineframes1.html" > </iframe>
```

This resolved the issue for myself.

Answer (score 0):

just close the iframe please :)

try this :

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<SITE URL>"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```